# Find the maximum product between two different numbers in an array. The product also has to be a multiple of 3

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, integer

The code below finds the biggest product pair, but it still doesn't make sure that the numbers are different and that the product is a multiple of 3.

let arr = [1, 4, 3, 6, 9, 9];

For instance, the answer for the above array should be 9x6=54 (product of the highest different numbers that is also multiple of 3) but my current code result is
9x9=81.

Important observation, the given array can contain positive and negative numbers also.

Does anyone have any tips?

```
// product in array of Integers
function maxProduct(arr, n)
{
     
    // Sort the array
    arr.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
     
    let  num1, num2;
     
    // Calculate product of two smallest numbers
    let sum1 = arr[0] * arr[1];
     
    // Calculate product of two largest numbers
    let sum2 = arr[n - 1] * arr[n - 2];
     
    // print the pairs whose product is greater
    if (sum1 > sum2)
    {
        num1 = arr[0];
        num2 = arr[1];
    }
    else
    {
        num1 = arr[n - 2];
        num2 = arr[n - 1];
    }
    document.write("Max product pair = " +
                 "{" + num1 + "," + num2 + "}");
}

</script>
```

Comment: I am confident that an O(n) solution exist, no sorting needed.

Comment: Marília, Better to roll back this latest edit.  If you have a new question, post a new question and not fundamentally change this one with its good answers.  I also suggest adding a link to the new question to this one to show how its is related, but different.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you are right. I am sorry. Didn't know you could rollback an edit. Already asked the new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71752857/given-an-array-of-integers-i-must-find-the-maximum-product-between-to-numbers

Comment: Did not [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71572566/2410359) satisfy both questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

1. Split the array into `multiples_of_3` (M3) and `non_multiples_of_3` (NM3).
2. Find top 2 largest numbers from M3 and NM3. Your answer will always include largest M3.
3. Note that your use case needs distinct largest numbers. That needs to be taken care of. eg. In python, you can convert input list to set etc.
4. Find the largest number of the remaining 3.

This will always work for an array of positive numbers. If there are -ve numbers as well, then, -ve numbers will only be part of solution if both selected are -ve. In which case, you can repeat the steps for only -ve numbers in the input and compare.

Complexity: O(n) : 2 traversals, one to split the array into M3 and NM3, next to select largest M3 and 3 other candidates for +ve and -ve values.

Comment: This is the right answer, but you should mention that you need to remove all duplicate values first (or that 'top 2 largest numbers' means 'top 2 largest distinct numbers')

Comment: I believe if there are 2 seperate occurences of the largest number, that should be the answer, no? In OP's example, he has only one `9` in input array.

Comment: Are you sure? The input they gave is `arr = [1, 4, 3, 6, 9, 9]`

Comment: My bad, I'll edit to incorporate that.

Answer (score 1):

An `O(N)` time, `O(1)` extra space algorithm:

1. Traverse the array, keep track of two variables: `max_multiple_of_three` and `min_multiple_of_three`
2. Traverse the array, keep track of two variables: `largest_number_in_array` (which shouldn't be equal to `max_multiple of three`) and `smallest_number_in_array` (which shouldn't be equal to `min_multiple_of_three`)
3. The answer will be either `max_multiple_of_three * largest_number_in_array` or `min_multiple_of_three * smallest_number_in_array`

Comment: You don't need to sort. If all the numbers are non-negative, pick the largest number, and the next-largest (that's a multiple of 3 if the largest isn't). Then you solve it in O(n) comparisons rather than O(n log n) comparisons.\

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm not sure if I understand your point. The algorithm would return `-3000` and `-3` without iterating the remaining array

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica then it returns `-3` and `1`, which is the right answer

Comment: @PaulHankin converted it to `O(N)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I understand what you're getting at, modified the answer

Comment: I think you have got it.  The trick being that sometimes the max product is sometimes  from a negative and positive as in [-3, 1, 10, 100] --> -3 * 1

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I rolledback the edit and decided to ask the question in a new post So the answres in this post are still valid. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71752857/given-an-array-of-integers-i-must-find-the-maximum-product-between-to-numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
function maxProduct(arr) {
    let a = 0;
    let b = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<=arr.length; i++){
        if(a == 0){
            if(arr[i]>a) a = arr[i];
        } else {
            if(arr[i]>a) {
                b = a;
                a = arr[i];
            } else {
                if(arr[i]>b) b = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return a*b;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).