# In an array of numbers find higest product with specific multiple

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, integer

The task was given an array of integers, find the maximum product between two numbers from the array, that is a multiple of 3.

```
</script>
arr = [-9, -11, 4, 6, 9, 7]; 
arr2 = [-11, 4, 6, 7]; 
arr3 = [11, 3, 5]

function findProduct(arr) {
  let maxProduct = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    
    
    for(let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      let product = arr[i] * arr[j]

      if(product % 3 !== 0) continue;
      
      if(product > maxProduct) {
        maxProduct = product
      }
    }
  }

  return maxProduct
}

console.log(findProduct(arr))
console.log(findProduct(arr2))
console.log(findProduct(arr3))
</script>
´´´´
```

Comment: The answer for the first array will be `99`, not `63`

Comment: Corner cases: Note that above code fails with set [-3 1] as the max product is -3 and code reports 0.  With set [1,2,4], code reports 0 when there is no solution.  Perhaps set `let maxProduct = most_negative_value;` and use `most_negative_value` as an error indication.  `arr[i] * arr[j]` may overflow and that is another issue.  Ahh - so many details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `O(N)` time, `O(1)` extra space algorithm:

1. Traverse the array, keep track of two variables: `max_multiple_of_three` and `min_multiple_of_three`
2. Traverse the array, keep track of two variables: `largest_number_in_array` (which shouldn't have the same index as `max_multiple of three`) and `smallest_number_in_array` (which shouldn't have same index as `min_multiple_of_three`)
3. The answer will be either `max_multiple_of_three * largest_number_in_array` or `min_multiple_of_three * smallest_number_in_array`

##### Example 1:

```
arr = [-9, -11, 4, 6, 9, 7]

max_multiple_of_three = 9
min_multiple_of_three = -9
largest_number_in_array = 7
smallest_number_in_array = -11

ans = max(-9*-11, 9*7) = 99
```

##### Example 2:

```
arr = [-11, 4, 6, 7]

max_multiple_of_three = 6
min_multiple_of_three = 6
largest_number_in_array = 7
smallest_number_in_array = -11

ans = max(6*-11, 6*7) = 42
```

Comment: Looks a lot like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71572566/2410359).  Unclear why that did not meet OP's goals.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that's correct. OP should delete the older question imo, doesn't make sense to have identical copies of the same question

Comment: If questions are fundamentally the same, make more sense to delete new post then the older one with 2 answers.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the only difference I see is an `O(N)` constraint, so that's also a valid point. OP should explain the need for a new question

Comment: IAC, "(which shouldn't be equal to max_multiple of three" appears incorrect. I think it should be "(which shouldn't be equal to _the index of_ the max_multiple of three".  Consider cases where the max_multiple of 3 occurs multiple times.  Earlier question has "make sure that the numbers are different", this does not.

Comment: I added a new question because @chux suggested that I did not edit the other post because it had good answers that where going to be lost so I rolled back. I am a begginer and 'm trying my best to please everyone. I'm sorry if I anoyed any of you. Please remember how frustration this can be when you are a begginer. A few things in the task changed, so I created a new post. I´m sure Abhinav answer is great but I don't understand what it means to traverse an array. I am researching it.

Comment: @Marília traverse an array means looping through it. Also, from what I can see, the answers there were already meeting your new constraints

Comment: @Abhinav So each time you said to traverse the array it should be a new loop where I store the number in a variable? Or just one loop?

Comment: @Marília total of two loops

Comment: Aside from overflow concerns of step 3 (if thats possible), looks good.